# Programming with USB Missile Launcher under Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, usb

Just got today these ones:
http://www.pearl.de/a-PE5858-1413.shtml

I want to start programming with these, but I can't find anything usable. I'm using Ubuntu Jaunty 9.04. The Problem is that I couldn't find much samples and modules etc. for my modell.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your missile launcher?

Comment: What is the product's manufacturer and model name/number?

Answer (score 1):

Is [**this**](http://www.henning-mersch.de/blog.html?showFullFrom=138&showMaxFull=1&showMaxEntries=-1) any good?

> Some days ago, I ordered a c-enter USB Missile Launcher Pan Tilt  (PE5858) from Pearl. I thought it has to be real fun and ... and I immediately found a  Python Script (new homepage on Feb 2009) for Linux support !

The script is called [**pymissile**](http://code.google.com/p/pymissile/).

Comment: I tried these, but I got Problems with the file "pyusb.c"
But I installed the required packages . . .

Answer (score 1):

there's a few perl modules (http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module;query=missile) which almost certainly aren't written for your missile launcher but their sources might be helpful.